# Selecting an appropriate similarity metric of a k-means clustering model

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I 'm using k-means algorithm for clustering my data.
I have 5 thousand samples. .(Each of my sample is about a customer. to analyse customer value I 'm going to clustering them base on 4 behavior features.)
The distance is calculated using the Euclidean metric and Pearson correlation.

I need to know

I don't know Euclidean distance is the correct method for calculating distances or Pearson correlation? 
I 'm using silhouette to validate my clustering. when I'm using Pearson correlation silhouette value  is more than when I use Euclidean metric.
Whether this means that Pearson correlation is more appropriate for distance metric?

Answer (score 0):

#### k-means does not support arbitrary distances.

It is based on variance minimization, which corresponds to (squared) Euclidean distance.

With Peason correlation, it will fail badly.

See this answer for an example how k-means fails badly with Pearson:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335448/1060350

short summary: **the *mean* does not work for Pearson**, but k-means is based on computing means. Use PAM or a similar method instead that uses medoids.

Comment: If the mean does not work for Pearson, how we can choose correlation as distance in k-means algorithm in command matlab?see:http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/kmeans.html

Comment: Users want to try it. Even if it isn't sensible... Because some textbooks say you assign by distance (not generally correct, you assign by least-squares, which happens to be least-euclidean). So users call for the option to change distances, and developers give in.